# Синтаксис оператора new

Tags: c++, операторы

[Вот здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) предоставлен прототип оператора new :

```
void* operator new (std::size_t size);
```

Но почему он используется с помощью совсем другого синтаксиса, например:

```
int *a = new int;
```

Т.е. почему не пишутся круглые скобки и за место `sizeof(TYPE)` просто `TYPE`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Использование оператора `new` обладает специальными свойствами. Когда он используется непосредственно как оператор в составе выражения (`new expression`), как в вашем примере:

```
 int* a = new int;
```

то компилятор делает три вещи:

- вызовет *функцию* `void* operator new (std::size_t size);` для выделения памяти под создаваемый объект
- вызовет конструктор создаваемого объекта (в данном примере отсутствует)
- сгенерирует код обработки исключений, выбрасываемых из конструктора (в данном примере отсутствует)

Однако можно явно использовать непосредственно саму функцию `operator new` для выделения куска неинициализированной памяти:

```
void * p = ::operator new(sizeof(int));
```

Тут никакой магии нет, это обычный вызов функции.

Стоить отметить, что большинство других операторов также можно вызывать "как операторы" и "как функции", например:

```
 struct MyStruct;

 bool operator ==(MyStruct const & left, MyStruct const & right);

 MyStruct x;
 MyStruct y
 if(x == y) // синтаксис оператора
 if(::operator ==(x, y)) // синтаксис функции
```

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, где можно посмотреть информацию о таких неявных действиях операторов. (на `cplusplus` я смог только обнаружить информацию о синтаксисах функций `new`)

Comment: @Vitaly Лучше смотреть на [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Operators). Специальные свойства есть только у специальных операторов, отдельно перечисленных на той странице.

Answer (score 1):

потому что у оператора `new` много способов использования.

Вот это вариант:

`int* a = new int;`

выделяет память из кучи и инициализирует объект, вызывая какой-нибудь конструктор.

Этот вариант:

`void* operator new (std::size_t size);`

только выделяет память и возвращает указатель на эту область не инициализуруя объект, подобно тому как работает функция `malloc` из языка С.

**Update**

Перевожу специально для вас из того ресурса:

```
  MyClass * p1 = new MyClass;
      // выделяет память вызывая operator new (sizeof(MyClass))
      // затем строит объект в этой области памяти
```

Comment: А где на этом сайте сказано о других способах использования? По моему там только выложены 3 прототипа подобных malloc из С

Comment: @Vitaly эти 3 и есть все способы использования оператора `new`

Comment: так вариант `void* operator new TYPE;` не присутствует на этом сайте. Есть только лишь:

`void* operator new (std::size_t size);`   

`void* operator new (std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_value) noexcept;`   


`void* operator new (std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept;`

Comment: @Vitaly потому что нету такого оператора.

Comment: тогда `int* a = new int;` какой из этих трех способов  использует?

Comment: @Vitaly неплохо было бы вам научиться читать техническую литературу. Этот вариант использует первый и третий в совокупности, тоесть сначала выделяя память затем инициализируется объект

Comment: у меня сложилось впечатление, что сначала в тех литературе приводятся конструкции в общем виде, а затем на примерах показываются частные случаи применения. В данной статье, в синтаксисах нету общей конструкции, позволяющий написать что-то подобное `MyClass * p1 = new MyClass;`. Этот пример приводится в конце и в комментариях написано, что это магическая запись означает.